# Can powershell check the home directories against a domain group and list differences?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a Windows server 2008 vm "hostname1" with 3200 directories in C:\Users.  Access to the vm is controlled by an AD group "usrhostname1".  Is there a powershell or command prompt method to check the list of users in C:\users against the domain group "usrhostname1" and output a list of the names in C:\Users that are not in "usrhostname1"

I am trying to clean up the users and that would help get the low hanging fruit of users whom no longer have access to the domain group.  I have taken over an environment where they did not clean up users as they left.

Comment: Yes, powershell can do this.

Comment: You know we do not write scripts on requst, don't you?  ;-) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything as I was not aware if it was possible.  The purpose of the question was to find out if it was possible and hopefully be provided a link where I could read on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would enumerate the group member's SIDs:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$GroupSids = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity usrhostname1 -Recursive | ForEach-Object { $_.SID.Value }
```

And your domain's SID:

```
$DomainSids = Get-AdDomain -Identity YourDomain | ForEach-Object { $_.DomainSID.Value }
```

Then I'd use WMI to enumerate the profiles, filter those that aren't above, and output the folders:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special = 'False'" |
    Where-Object { ($_.SID -notin $GroupSids) -and ($_.SID -match $DomainSids) } | 
    Select-Object -Property LocalPath
```

The Special profiles are All Users, Default User, Public, etc.  Filtering to the SIDs that match your domain SID will prevent the script from touching local users like the local Administrator account.

Or, alternately, just remove them:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special = 'False'" |
    Where-Object { ($_.SID -notin $GroupSids) -and ($_.SID -match $DomainSids) } | 
    Remove-CimInstance
```

`Remove-CimInstance` is nice with `Win32_UserProfile` objects because it purges the profiles from the system's registry information and the profile folders.

Obviously, be careful with that.  You'll want to verify that you're not capturing profiles you don't want to keep.  I also wouldn't use this method at all if your system is a domain controller.